# How to give PS3 controllers charging handshake on connected powered hub?

Tags: usb-power, usb-hub, lakka

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a powered USB Hub ( 7 port Anker ) running retro game OS Lakka.  The PS3 controllers work great with the system, but I want to be able to charge them as well.

Currently if I plug in the controller to the hub the power lite on the hub comes on for a few seconds and turns off and no charging happens.  If I disconnect the hub from the pi, the power light on the hub doesn't turn on at all, upon plugging in a controller and no charging happens.  In another part of the house I have the same 7 port hub connected to an iMac and when I plug a controller in there, the hub power light comes on and stays on and the controller charging lights begin to flash.

I understand from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73919/what-wall-plug-chargers-can-be-used-to-charge-ps3-controllers) that the controllers require a "handshake" to start charging off of a usb connection.  Is there a way to make the pi do this?